# Error while sending the Email when the app is hosted in AWS?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Actually I'm using Amazon SES for sending emails in my application. In my local machine I'm able to send mail to recipient address but in QA it's not working.
I get following error:

> "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Comment: ref https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure/

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours research for the above issue I was able to send the mail in my QA environment which is hosted in Amazon Web Services.I'm using SMTP client which is using System.Net Namespace.I searched in Microsoft official documentation and this aricle [SMTP ISSUE Resolver](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Programmatically-send-SMTP-e9f8e8d9)

Please follow the above article we can easily solve the problem.

Thanks
**Kartheek Gummaluri**